# Accessing data from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, extract

I am quite new with JSON. My code consists in extracting data from a website wich requires a API key. Having extracted the information. I am trying to reach the information which is encoded in son through this format (here is a sample):

```
[{"number":31705,"name":"31705 - CHAMPEAUX (BAGNOLET)","address":"RUE DES CHAMPEAUX (PRES DE LA GARE ROUTIERE) - 93170 BAGNOLET","latitude":48.8645278209514,"longitude":2.416170724425901},{"number":10042,"name":"10042 - POISSONNIÈRE - ENGHIEN","address":"52 RUE D'ENGHIEN / ANGLE RUE DU FAUBOURG POISSONIERE - 75010 PARIS","latitude":48.87242006305313,"longitude":2.348395236282807}]
```

How do i access the different data in the json code ? This is the code i have come up with:

```
import requests

reponse=requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/{station_number}?contract={contract_name}&api_key HTTP/1.1')
```

I Believe that my request has formulated a response which lies in the "response" "folder" that has been sent by the website to my computer:

```
print(reponse.headers)
print(reponse(2,/'latitude')
```

I am trying to access the information of lattitude in every element of the json code - the 2 represents the second element of the list and lattitude the name of the value i am trying to access within the element of the json list. But i can't manage to do it. The error I get is a syntax error.

How do I fix it? I would like to access to all the value of each string of each member of the object 'response'.

UPDATE n°1:

My new code is:

```
import json
import requests
reponse=requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/{31705}?contract={Paris}&apiKey={0617697a9795f803697de4b9abf9759d5406b3a0}  HTTP/1.1')
data = json.loads(response.content)
print(data)
```

However i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/someone/Desktop/TIPE 2016:17/Programme TIPE 2016:2017.py", line 27, in <module>
data = json.loads(response.content)
  File "/Users/someone/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

UPDATE n°2:

my new code is :

```
import json
import requests
reponse=requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/{31705}?contract={Paris}&apiKey={0617697a9795f803697de4b9abf9759d5406b3a0}  HTTP/1.1')
data = response.json()
latitude = data[2]['latitude']
```

However i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/someone/Desktop/TIPE 2016:17/Programme TIPE 2016:2017.py", line 30, in <module>
latitude = data[2]['latitude']
KeyError: 2
```

Does it mean that response is empty ?

UPDATE n°3:

```
reponse.content
```

the answer is the following:

```
b'{ "error" : "Unauthorized" }'
```

What is the problem ?

UPDATE n°4:

my new code is :

```
reponse=requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/{31705}?contract={Paris}&apiKey={0617697a9795f803697de4b9abf9759d5406b3a0}  HTTP/1.1')

data =  json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(reponse.headers)
print(reponse.content)
```

the result is :

```
{'Content-Length': '48', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'Date': 'Fri, 23 Sep 2016 19:39:25 GMT', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
b'{ "error" : "Unauthorized" }'
```

so the answer to my request is not empty but i do not have the authorization to access it. How can I solve this ?

FINAL UPDATE:

The new and working code is :

```
import json

import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/31705?contract=Paris&apiKey=0617697a9795f803697de4b9abf9759d5406b3a0')

response_json = r.json()

print (response_json['name'])
```

and the result is:

```
31705 - CHAMPEAUX (BAGNOLET)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `print(reponse(2,/'latitude')`, because it lacks a closing bracket `)` and `/'latitude'` argument is strange.

Comment: I am trying to access the information of lattitude in every element of the json code - the 2 represents the second element of the list and lattitude the name of the value i am trying to access within the element of the json list. But i can't manage to do it.

Comment: could you check what is the value of `response.content`?

Comment: Oh it says :    b'{ "error" : "Unauthorized" }'     what does it mean ?

Comment: You are making an unauthorized request. Your auth token is not set properly.

Comment: I have an API key ? is it not enough ? and how do i change my auth token ?

Comment: Not its not. Your website must require some kind of authorization. Authentication mechanism varies from site to site. What you could do is do the same operation from webpage and monitor the what http messages are being sent.
If you can get the API documentation OR can get in touch with development team they could also help you with this

Answer (score 1):

you could convert your `json` data to dict and then access it like dictionary.
I believe it should be something like

`data =  json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: it doesn't work it says : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/someone/Desktop/TIPE 2016:17/Programme TIPE 2016:2017.py", line 24, in <module>
    data = json.loads(response.content)
  File "/Users/someone/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: @ElliottOhayon yes for this to work content should be of string type.

Comment: Your auth token is not set. that is the reason you are getting error.

Comment: I am sorry i am new with json but what what should i change in my code ? how do i set my auth token ?

Comment: I have edited my code to get it work for no str responses

Comment: the answer i got after trying your modified code was : b'{ "error" : "Unauthorized" }' i

Answer (score 1):

You've messed up your url. I'm not sure what's about `HTTP/1.1` suffix, but id definitely does not belong here. Also, all parameters in curled brackets looks off.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/31705?contract=Paris&apiKey=0617697a9795f803697de4b9abf9759d5406b3a0')
response_json = r.json()
print response_json
```

This code snippet prints:

```
{u'status': u'OPEN', u'contract_name': u'Paris', u'name': u'31705 - CHAMPEAUX (BAGNOLET)', u'bonus': True, u'bike_stands': 50, u'number': 31705, u'last_update': 1474660046000, u'available_bike_stands': 49, u'banking': True, u'available_bikes': 1, u'address': u'RUE DES CHAMPEAUX (PRES DE LA GARE ROUTIERE) - 93170 BAGNOLET', u'position': {u'lat': 48.8645278209514, u'lng': 2.416170724425901}}
```

To sum up, `response_json` is now a standard Python dict, from which data may be accessed using standard dict protocol.

```
print response_json['status']  # prints OPEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Requests has a builtin JSON decoder, so there's no need to use the json library:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
```

Based on the details in your question, "data" *might* be a list of dicts that contain latitude.  So to extract the first one might be:

```
latitude = data[0]['latitude']
```

But you'll probably want to play with the response interactively first to make sure.